# Can i query list items from another sharepoint instance with a different domain?

Tags: javascript, jquery

Our parent company shares the same network as us however we have a different SharePoint instance. We are trying to dynamically pull some content from their instance via JavaScript or some other method.

Our users would have access to the content if they visited it directly however we are trying to massage the content a little before delivery to our users.

Any suggestions on how to approach this?

I have tried things such as this to no avial:

```
    $(document).ready(function () {
        $.ajax({
            type: 'GET',
            url: 'https://sharepoint.anotherdomain.com/site/_vti_bin/ListData.svc/Listname',
           dataType: 'xml',

            success: function (data) {
                console.log(data);
            },
            error: console.log('Err')
        });
    });
```

Answer (score 0):

Try to modify your Search Content Sources and add the other farm into your search results.  Things to look up (google) include: Federated Results, Search Scopes, Content Sources and Managed Properties.